# How to jailbreak iphone 4gs in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, iphone

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I didn't realize how to make it fully friendly with my iPhone 4Gs. How I would load it into my phone without iTunes?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: It has updated to 5.01. It's the main problem.
It gets unlocked just for a while and then locked again.
sorry for bad english.

Comment: As I am a new here.so Don't forget to vote my question.plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first downgrade it. Then try again to jailbreak it..
Good luck..

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? It could of great for future readers.

Answer (score -2):

Here you go chief: http://www.ijailbreak.com/jailbreak/download-absinthe-2-0-ios-5-1-1-untethered-jailbreak-mac-windows/

Comment: Even tough this might be the answer to the user's issue it is recommended that the information from the linked page is presented as a post containing all the necessary information in it. Don't just link pages from the Internet.